# Simplify method to ensure time is in correct format

Tags: javascript, time

I have the following piece of code

```
 function isProperTimeForm(clockTime)
{
    return     (clockTime.length == 8) 
            && (isDecimal(clockTime.charAt(0))) 
            && (isDecimal(clockTime.charAt(1)))
            && (clockTime.charAt(2) == ':')
            && (isDecimal(clockTime.charAt(3)))
            && (isDecimal(clockTime.charAt(4)))
            && (clockTime.charAt(5) == ':')
            && (isDecimal(clockTime.charAt(6)))
            && (isDecimal(clockTime.charAt(7)));
}

function isDecimal(c) 
{
    return c <= '9' && c >= '0';
}
```

which, as you can probably tell, is a function I'm using to determine whether a user gave input in the proper "hh:mm:ss" form for a textbox that is meant to take in a string representing a time in hours, minutes and seconds.

I don't like the look of my code and I'm wondering if there's a simpler and fancier way of doing it.

Comment: Use a regular expression for that. `/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/` - much simpler, IMOHO. (Note that this regular expression, like the original code, tests for *format* but not *correctness*. That is, it should be used in *conjunction* with actual logic to detect that `99:88:77` is garbage even though it's a "valid format".)

Comment: Delete this question and ask on Code Review.

Comment: (Too late now. Flagged for migration.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
function isProperTimeForm(clockTime) {
    return /^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test(clockTime);
}
```

If you're not familiar with regex syntax, here's what each piece does:

- `^` and `$` anchor the regular expression to ensure it applies to the entire string. Without this, the regex could match a *part* of the string and still return true.
- `\d` represents a single digit.
- `{2}` means there are exactly two of the preceding match, in this case `\d`. This makes this equivalent to `\d\d`.
- `:` just represents a literal colon.

If you want to verify that the time could be a real time (i.e. not something like 45:73:89), you could use a more complicated regular expression:

```
// 12-hour time:
/^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$/

// 24-hour time:
/^(2[0-3]|[01]\d):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$/
```

Comment: If translating into other languages: make sure that `\d` matches ASCII digits (as opposed to all Unicode numerals; I would probably just use `[0-9]`, but that's a matter of taste) and that `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a string (as opposed to the beginning and end of a line).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to do this. For a tutorial, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **regex**:

```
^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$
```

**Example:**

```
/^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$/.exec('12:20:30');
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # Start of string
(?:                 # Try to match...
 (?:                #  Try to match...
  ([01]?\d|2[0-3]): #   HH:
 )?                 #  (optionally).
 ([0-5]?\d):        #  MM: (required)
)?                  # (entire group optional, so either HH:MM:, MM: or nothing)
([0-5]?\d)          # SS (required)
$                   # End of string
```

If the pattern is ok it returns an array of the splitted string else it returns null

*Regular expression are much faster when it comes to text/string manipulation.*

Hope this helps.

Keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing such a feature (from scratch), I would use a combination of a regular expression for the format and conditional logic to check on the component ranges.

The following is for a 12-hour clock but, *by keeping the logic separate*, it can be trivially altered to support a 24-hour clock format - or even partial formats like "9:00".

```
function validTime(time) {
    // check format - \d{2} means "match two digits 0..9"
    var m = (time || "").match(/^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/)
    // check correctness
    return (m
        && m[1] > 0 && m[1] <= 12
        && m[2] <= 59
        && m[3] <= 59)
}

validTime()            // -> false
validTime("00:11:22")  // -> false (no 00 on 12-hour clock)
validTime("12:59:59")  // -> true
validTime("23:59:59")  // -> false (no 23 on 12-hour clock)
```

The above code relies on several observations:

1. `str <= num` is roughly equivalent to `parseFloat(str) <= num`
2. Every captured string will be in the range "00" - "99".